# Why is the JetBrains IDE keeps saying Class and Constructor are unused?

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, es6-class

My PhpStorm / WebStorm IDE keeps telling, that the `class` and `constructor` are unused for some classes (not for all). I have already set the JavaScript language version to `ECMAScript6` and enabled Node.js support in settings. The code in general works fine too. For example ...

**File TestClass.js:**

```
module.exports = class Test {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Test.constructor");
    }

    test() {
        console.log("Test.test");
    }
}
```

**File Test.js:**

```
let Test = require("./TestClass");
let inst = new Test();
inst.test();
```

With this, code inspections keeps telling me:

> Unused class TestClass
>   Unused method constructor

Is there anything wrong or is there a way to suppress the warning? The IDE in general displays no option to suppress this.

Even another problem seems to be, that anonymous classed causes inspection problems too. If I rewrite `module.exports = class Test {` to `module.exports = class {` even the method `test()` inside the class will be marked as `unused`. I haven't found a way to prevent this too ...

Comment: I think, you can suppress "unused class and methods" inspection in File - Preferences - Code Inspection - JS. I'm not sure with the path, because I worked with PhpStorm 6 month ago, but it was something like that.

Comment: @JirkaPicek But this will disable the inspection for the whole project. That would work, but has a bigger impact. I would like to have the inspection, but to work correct. ;)

Comment: @Gimby Sure, that has to be enabled. But that is already enabled in my project. I've extended the question to this.

Comment: I know you found solution already, but if you would like to disable just some specific inspections in future, there is in [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Modifiers_Style.html) in Alt+Enter menu Inspection... -> Disable once with comment -> Disable <Your selection>. I guess something simillar is in PhpStorm.

Comment: @JirkaPicek Yes, that was one thing I was searching for at first. But it seems like there is no option to suppress such warnings. In know the Alt+Enter function, but there is nothing happen on this lines. There is even no suppress entry in the context menu of the warning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that I just needed to ask here, to find the answer by myself. ;)

The problem seems to belong to the inline export of the `class`. When creating the `class` first, and then `export` it afterwards by the `class name` resolves the problem.

So I just had to rewrite my class files like this:

```
class Test { // instead of module.exports = class Test {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Test.constructor");
    }
}

module.exports = Test; // put the export to an extra line
```

Comment: More a patch than a solution, but I guess it works. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! The is the only help in all of the web, so far. Exporting the class directly no longer has "unused method" issues. BUT requiring the module and calling the constructor would not hint the parameters. It would only recognize the constructor with `MyClass.prototype.constructor()`. Exporting the class at the end of the file caused the constructor to be recognized properly.